When i was a child, 50 years ago, i had a board game in which the players tried to gather the best photos of breaking news stories. can you help?
In the game, when you arrived at a news story, you would receive a "photo." The value of the photo, in points, was determined by how quickly you arrived at the scene. A valuable picture would be flames of a raging fire. A less valuable card would have a picture of a burned building and maybe some smoke.

There are two games that come to mind, https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2033/reporter and https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/5819/star-reporter - both are over 50 years old. Do you remember a bit more about the game?
